# fill gaps specified as "0" in 2D matrix not taking into account NaN

Tags: matlab, constraints, nan, nearest-neighbor

I'm working with a 2D matrix (global soiltype grid) that I want to fill up to fit a new mask. For that, my idea is to fill the blanks using an interpolation by nearest neighbor. I don't see how can I apply that interpolation just to the zeros, and not considering NaNs (which represent the sea). I was thinking about filling those blanks by hand as there aren't too many of them, but I thought that it's interesting to know how to do this anyway. I'd like grid cells representing islands in the middle of the ocean to consider the closest coast as nearest neighbor, if that makes sense. I know that's not realistic, but for my purposes is good enough.

Thank you in advance for any ideas. I don't play with Matlab very often and this kind of things are too much of a challenge timewise.

Comment: Please provide some example data (input and output)

Comment: Change the `NaN` for something else? Or d you need them as `NaN`? 
`mymatrix(isnan(mymatrix))=-999;`

Comment: So you have a large matrix with values and then NaN's.  You want to replace with the 0's with real values and preserve the NaN's.  I assume that interpolation with nearest neighbor means you want to replace the 0 with the closest (space-wise) non-zero value?  Is that correct?

Comment: @Ander, I'd say that my main problem are the islands in the ocean. If for example I have a matrix 'A = [1 3 5 2 0 NaN NaN NaN; 0 4 1 7 4 NaN NaN 0; 9 7 2 5 0 Nan NaN NaN]' I want the 0 at the end of the second row to be assigned a value based on the nearest 'not-NaN' neighbor, which in this case would be 4. I hope that makes more sense, sorry for not explaining it properly the first time

Comment: @Dan, I hope the example I gave to Ander makes it a bit more clear :-)

Comment: @user4004132 so your definition of neighbor is along the row in the example.  What about column-wise or diagonal?

Comment: @user4004132 It would be much clearer if you added your updates to the question itself rather than in the comments.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use the function isnan() of matlab.

 
Here's un example:

```
A = [1 0 4, 0 3 NaN, NaN 4 5, 0 0 0, NaN 1 NaN]


A =
1       0     4
0       3     NaN
NaN     4     5
0       0     0
NaN     1     NaN
```

By using `isnan(A)` will return you a matrix with 1's where there are NaN's and 0 elsewhere.

```
isnan(A)

ans =

     0     0     0
     0     0     1
     1     0     0
     0     0     0
     1     0     1
```

Then you can use the returned matrix (same size as A) as a mask for something else and/or replace the NaN's with whatever you want.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer :-). I don't think that would work for my purposes, as my matrix is a 720x360 with islands in the middle of the ocean that I don't want to be changed by NaNs, if that makes sense. Thank you anyway! :-)

Answer (score 0):

This is what I came up with.

```
function result = nonNanNearestNeighbor(A)
[gridX, gridY] = meshgrid(1:size(A,2), 1:size(A,1));

%if you don't want periodic BCs change function below
t = PeriodicBC(gridY - 1, size(A,1));
b = PeriodicBC(gridY + 1, size(A,1));
l = PeriodicBC(gridX - 1, size(A,2));
r = PeriodicBC(gridX + 1, size(A,2));

%Convert from rc notation to index notation
T = sub2ind(size(A), t, gridX);
B = sub2ind(size(A), b, gridX);
L = sub2ind(size(A), gridY, l);
R = sub2ind(size(A), gridY, r);

%Shift the stencils until they're not nans
    while any(isnan(A(T(:))))
        [tNaN, gX] = ind2sub(size(A), T(isnan(A(T))));
        T(isnan(A(T))) = sub2ind(size(A), PeriodicBC(tNaN - 1, size(A,1)), gX);
    end

    while any(isnan(A(B(:))))
        [bNaN, gX] = ind2sub(size(A), B(isnan(A(B))));
        B(isnan(A(B))) = sub2ind(size(A), PeriodicBC(bNaN + 1, size(A,1)), gX);
    end

    while any(isnan(A(L(:))))
        [gY, lNaN] = ind2sub(size(A), L(isnan(A(L))));
        L(isnan(A(L))) = sub2ind(size(A), gY, PeriodicBC(lNaN - 1, size(A,2)));
    end

    while any(isnan(A(R(:))))
        [gY, rNaN] = ind2sub(size(A), R(isnan(A(R))));
        R(isnan(A(R))) = sub2ind(size(A), gY, PeriodicBC(rNaN + 1, size(A,2)));
    end

result = (A(T) + A(B) + A(L) + A(R)) / 4;

end

function shifted = PeriodicBC(shifted, value)
    shifted(shifted <= 0) = value - shifted(shifted <= 0);
    shifted(shifted > value) = shifted(shifted > value) - value;

    if any((shifted(:) <= 0) | (shifted(:) > value))
        shifted = PeriodicBC(shifted, value);
    end
end
```

Comment: you're amazing. I'll give it a go and let you know how it went. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: I just tried it and it didn't go as well as it seemed, unfortunately :-(. That function seems to interpolate the values while the number is not a NaN, but that blurred the lines between soil classes and lost the islands values, for what it seemed. Thank you anyway, that was a lot of effort put into helping, you're a very kind human being. I finally opted for a wrong but good enough for my purposes way around: doing that by hand :-). Thanks a lot again for the help. All the best